# MapReduce with extended objects as Key for reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement map and reduce with custom objects like this:

Mapper:

```
public class SommeMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Entity, Entity>
```

Reducer:

```
public class SomeReducer extends Reducer<Entity,Entity, NullWritable, Text>
```

While I have three objects as Key that can go into reducer:

```
Entity implements WitableComparable
```

`A extends Entity`

`B extends Entity`

While I am calling `Context.write` with A or B

I got the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected Entity, recieved A
```

Can someone point if I can use inmhertance in Keys for reduction?

Comment: try to add A and B after casting to Entity in mapper class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the ouput key/value class for your mapper during the creation of your job:

```
conf.setOutputKeyClass(Entity.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(Entity.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, already did it. Eventually ended with looking into hadoop code. Looks like you cannot pass any other object than you declared even if it extends from it.

Comment: Yes you can: if you define org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation as output you can write both Put and Delete, so I think you can do the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a wrapper class for A and B? Class C { A val1; B val2; } or Class C {Entity val;}

Comment: This is what I exactly did